# 'Add to Cart' button fails using 'Display: inline' in in Agile Web Development with Rails (4th edition)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I cannot make my 'Add to Cart' button inline next to the product price, for some reason that I do not understand, the button appears below the product price.

Here my development settings:

ruby 1.9.3p392

rails 4.0.0.rc2

I following the DEPOT project and I am stuck in ITERATION D3 where the author insert a button next to the product price through the following CSS code:

```
#store .entry form, #store .entry form div {
display: inline;
}
```

and my views/store/index.html.erb as follow:

```
<% if notice %>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% end %>

<h1>Your Pragmatic Catalog</h1>

<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <div class="entry">
    <%= image_tag(product.image_url) %>
    <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
    <%= sanitize(product.description) %>
  <div class="price_line">
      <span class="price"><%= number_to_currency(product.price) %></span>
      <%= button_to 'Add to Cart' , line_items_path(:product_id => product) %>
  </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Also I have reviewing the HTML rendered from Google Chrome:

```
<div class="price_line">
  <span class="price">$34.95</span>
  <form action="/line_items?product_id=4" class="button_to" method="post">
  <div><input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" /><input name="authenticity_token" 
  type="hidden" value="yTcDgb4x1h98dXnI0dQqHv4hjfqduSBPMwsLLL3GeHw=" />
  </div></form>
</div>
```

I have tested over Google Chrome, Firefox, IE9 and Opera. It seems that is not a problem related to browser. I need someone who can explain this weird behavior what could be the smartest way to solve it. :-)

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Try putting a comma after form in your css.

Comment: It does not work if I insert the comma after Form. That will leave the DIV alone, and the render breaks because is applying display: inline for every DIV. Remember that we need to affect the child DIV into the Form only.